# transparent bridge: is nat possible anyway with nftables?

Tags: networking

I two 10gb NICs(eth1,eth2) in one card configured as bridge(br0), and PC( with ubuntu 22.04)'s own nic(eth0) for accessing it, only. I am making this a transparent bridge for filtering undesired packets using nftables, with good result (just learning it, too).

I need to make portforward too. something like:

```
chain nat {
                type nat hook prerouting priority -199; policy accept;
                meta nftrace set 1
                iif eth1 ip daddr a.b.c.d tcp dport x counter dnat to e.f.g.h:y
        }
```

I know that it is not a network standard within a bridge, bridge nat is about modifying destination mac. I read about nft has not bridge l3 ip capabilities for now.

Anyway I am asking is there any workaround, two step operations with preferably with nft. At last, if it is not possible with nft, can I do it with xdp/bpf or something else ? I could not prefer this, compiling a c code for every new/modify entry with many other complications.

Thank in advance

I tried as below found in net:

```
table inet try1 {
        chain nat {
                type nat hook prerouting priority -199; policy accept;
                meta nftrace set 1
                ip daddr 10.100.10.9 tcp dport 50080 counter dnat to 10.100.10.10:80
        }
}

table bridge firewall {
        chain prer {
                type filter hook prerouting priority -300;
                meta nftrace set 1
                iif eth1 ip daddr 10.100.10.9 tcp dport 50080 meta pkttype set host ether daddr set bridge MAC counter
        }
        chain input {
                type filter hook input priority 0; policy accept;
        }
```

where bridge mac is different from mac's eth1, eth2(changed by me).

Accept bridge input was needed, also.

The inet table nat is triggered, but I do not know where these packets go. I could not find them anymore. Of course, the packets don't go out eth2 as I need (I do not need change direction of them, but normally eth1 <--> eth2). I think the above method is to change output in a multiport bridge, not this case